# При запросе html кода через bs4 приходит исходный код страницы, который отличается, что делать?

Tags: python, html, bs4

```
import urllib.request as ur
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


s = ur.urlopen("https://csgofastx.ru/game/double")
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")

title = soup.find("div", class_="game-bets-container")
print(title)
```

Answer (score 1):

Исходный код отличается тем, что там есть js скрипты которые генерируют страницы и обычным `request` js скрипты не загрузить

Простой вариант, загрузить страницу через `Selenium` и передать `html` в `bs4`